# How does AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

```
public class BackgroungTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    public Void doInBackground(String... params) {
       //tasks
       return;  //error occurs here!
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //codes
    }
}
```

The above class does not depend on return values. So onPostExceute() simply execute codes written in there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer this sites it, 1. [Asynchronous Task_tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) 2. [Example with Explanation of Asynchronous Task](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/)

Comment: `Void` and `void` are different, refer http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just return null.

```
public class BackgroungTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    public Void doInBackground(String... params) {
       //tasks
       return null; 
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //codes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to use "return null;" instead of just "return;", as `Void` is a class around the usual "void" value.

Answer (score 5):

In `doInBackGround` return null, as [`Void`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Void.html) is an object (does not = void)..

```
public class BackgroungTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

public Void doInBackground(String... params) {
   //tasks
   return null;  //error occurs here!
}

public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    //codes
}
}
```

Comment: You should also explain **why** you have to return `null` there.

Comment: Agree with @Luksprog, This isn't a answer.

Comment: It works that way! Well, if this isn't an answer, then what is the right one?

Answer (score 4):

AsyncTask works like this

> onPreExecute -> doInBackGround -> onPostExecute

Neglecting progressUpdates etc, as soon doInBackGround is complete, control goes to onPostExecute. A simple **return** disrupts this flow hence causing the error. To Solve this, replace with **return null** Since its a void. The return statement parameters are passed to onPostExecute as parameter, where you can use it to see wheter it has been successful.

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackGround` returns null value

```
public class BackgroungTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
 ....
 ....
}
```

check this [Android dev doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for asynchronous task in andorid